# Remove ACL from Windows Registry Key via Powershell

Tags: permissions, powershell, wifi, access-control-list, windows-registry

I am trying to create a startup script that can be distributed via GPO to laptops (running 64bit Windows 7 Professional) to make it impossible for any user (including local administrators) to display the passwords for connected wireless networks. I have this done mostly but cannot figure out how to remove Users/Groups from the security entries on the key.

This is what I have so far, it basically defines variables and changes the ownership of the key to the local "Administrators" group.

```
$hkey = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{86F80216-5DD6-4F43-953B-35EF40A35AEE}"
$exe = "\\server\share\SetACL.exe"
& $exe -on $hkey -ot reg -actn setowner -ownr n:'Administrators'
```

The end result of the script should remove "BUILTIN\Administrators", "BUILTIN\Users", "SERVICE\TrustedInstaller" from Security entries, **leaving only "BUILTIN\SYSTEM" with read** permissions, and then taking permission away from SYSTEM and giving them to BUILTIN\Administrators. This configuration has been tested and works.

In order to use get-acl you have to map a ps-drive to the hkcr hive (because it's an alias that points to both {hklm,hkcu}\SOFTWARE\Classes?) so I have this for that, if get-acl is even needed to remove permissions:

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
$dkey = "HKCR:\AppID\{86F80216-5DD6-4F43-953B-35EF40A35AEE}"
$acl = get-acl $dkey
```

I have found so much on the internet about adding deny permissions but I do not want to add deny, I just want to remove the entries as if clicking "remove" through properties>security.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't really need to map a PSDrive.  Updating the location `'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{86F80216-5DD6-4F43-953B-35EF40A35AEE}\'` should work.  - `I have decided to give permissions to "Domain Admins"` - Generally it is better to assign permissions to local groups, not domain groups.  That way things won't break if you lose access to the domain on that machine.

Comment: I understand and agree with your point but I was thinking giving local administrators ownership would grant them read access to the key, which I want to take away from them, but now that I think about it the ownership should just give them the ability to change permissions on the key, not to read it, which is not a problem.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that no matter what permissions you set, local administrators can always take ownership of any local object and "fix" the permissions so they can read/write/etc.

Comment: What's your concern about adding a deny to the ACL?

Comment: First instinct was, 'Use Set-ACL'.  Second is, 'This is a job for GPO.'

Comment: Group policy can natively set registry permissions via Computer Configuration->Policies->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Registry

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to remove a specific user from a Registry Key

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Rajiv

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule ("MYPC\TEST", "FullControl", "Allow")    

$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($AccessRule)

$acl | Set-Acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Rajiv
```

The above code removes the user `"MYPC\TEST"` user from the permission set of `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Rajiv` Key

[Manage File System ACL's using Powershell](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/04/18/how-to-manage-file-system-acls-with-powershell-scripts/)